# Share raster and code from Google Earth Engine workspace

Tags: google-earth-engine, import

I'm trying to find a way to share rasters and scripts on Google Earth Engine. Currently, it's pretty easy to send two links, one for the raster asset and another for the static code. Examples are shown below.

[image: raster image]

[image: code link]

Is there a way that I can share my raster assets in the code directly so that the recipient doesn't need two separate links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, click on your asset, this will open a window. Click on 'SHARE' and tick the box that says 'Anyone can read'.